# Webhosting with Tomcat

Tags: hosting, tomcat, web-hosting

Is there any good hosting company that comes with pre-installed Tomcat server (instead of the commonly Apache) in order to run JSP? Looking for something relatively cheap (like site5.com, mediatemple and softlayer plans for example).

Thanks,

Joel

Answer (score 0):

A very quick [google (hosting tomcat server)](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=hosting+tomcat+server&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-GB:official&client=firefox-a) showed me pages of hosting companies which allow you to run tomcat. The very first one allows various different versions of tomcat and quotes $4.00 per month. Go have a look at the links on the first page at least - you'll find something useful.

Comment: Thank you, googled it too. Just thought maybe there is one recommended by the experts here